# JS set style for size function

Tags: javascript

My JS function "set style for size" will not call the bodysmall CSS style sheet no mater how small I make the screen `width (screen.width <=480).`

However the function will call the bodysmall CSS style sheet if I reverse the function.

```
(screen.width >=480)
```

Which proves to me the JS function is working. I suspect there is something wrong with my event handler.
I am not familiar with JavaScript yet so any help would be greatly appreciated.

this is my code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setStyleForSize() {
    if (screen.width <= 481) {
        document.body.className = "bodySmall";
    }

else {
        document.body.className = "bodyNormal";
    }

}


function addEventHandler(oNode, evt, oFunc) {
    if (typeof(window.event) != "undefined")
        oNode.attachEvent("on"+evt, oFunc);
    else
        oNode.addEventListener(evt, oFunc, true);

}
addEventHandler(window, "load", function() { setStyleForSize(); } );
addEventHandler(window, "resize", function() { setStyleForSize(); } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one instead of yours:

```
function addEventHandler(oNode, evt, oFunc) {
    if ( document.addEventListener ) {
        oNode.addEventListener(evt, oFunc, false);
        return oFunc;
    } else if ( document.attachEvent ) {
        var bound = function() {
            return fn.apply(oNode, arguments);
        };
        oNode.attachEvent("on" + evt, bound);
        return bound;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** You can't specify which event handler has to be used with `typeof(window.event)`, so your `if` statement is incorrect

See the <kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9htr/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried this solution but the function did not call any style sheet at all !!

Comment: Hi yes I did take a look at the demo and the code works on the demo. but the problem I am experiencing is the code does not recognize a small screen. my code works fine if I reverse the function (screen.width >=481) instead of (screen.width <=481) and both stylesheets render the document as they should. but i cant get the function to recognize a small screen as in a mobile screen even if i reduce 481 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

[`screen.width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen.width) is never changes, use [`window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.innerWidth) instead:

```
function setStyleForSize() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 481) {
        document.body.className = "bodySmall";
    }

else {
        document.body.className = "bodyNormal";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried this one but nothing has changed, the web site still does not call the correct style sheet (bodysmall) it works for detecting anything larger that 481 but the function is not detecting a smaller screen.

Comment: The code seems works for me, if your style is not correct, please check again your CSS. Or you can give a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so I can take a look at it.

Comment: Hi TrungDQ My full code can be seen at www.webmasterkip.co.uk there are some test files on there, the index file and the two css files

Comment: Put the `<script>` section at the end of the page, right before the `</body>` close tag.

Comment: Hi TrungDQ Tried that one still no joy !!